# NASM error: parser instruction expected

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, nasm

```
 ;**********************************
 ; Boot1.asm
 ;      - A Simple Bootloader
 ;   Operating System Development
 ;**********************************

    org 0x7c00    ;BIOS loaded at 0x7c00

    bits 16       ; We are still in 16 bit real mode

     Start:
     cli      ; clear all interrupts
     hlt      ; halt the system

     times 510 - ($-$$) db 0  ;We have to be 512 bytes.Clear rest of bytes with 0

     ddw 0xAA55               ;Boot signature
```

I have written a simple boot-loader program in nasm on Windows 7 but I am getting an error:

```
 error:parser: instruction expected.
```

This problem has been solved previously but I am not getting it in my context.

Comment: I don't think there is any nasm assembler directive `ddw`.

Comment: I apologize for my mistake i have been stucked for hours on this.

Comment: Provide the entire error message.

Comment: @Gene You should write that as an answer since that's probably what causes the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NASM documents do not name an assembler directive `ddw`. I expect that's what the error message is talking about.  `ddw` is not an "instruction," so it's confused.